Extract Seasonality Directly from SARIMA in R
I want to extract the seasonality from my sarima model.
My dataset is in the format of this:
ds: dates
y: metric
This is weekly data
I have done the following:
ts_data <- ts(for_seasonality$y, frequency = 52, start = c(year(start_date), 1 + for_seasonality$week_num[1]))

sarima_model <- auto.arima(ts_data, seasonal = TRUE)

summary(sarima_model)

Series: ts_data 
ARIMA(0,1,2)(2,0,1)[52] with drift 

Coefficients:
          ma1      ma2    sar1    sar2    sma1   drift
      -0.4227  -0.1011  0.2145  0.1747  0.1393  0.0006
s.e.   0.0510   0.0558  0.5443  0.2208  0.5584  0.0023

sigma^2 = 0.003411:  log likelihood = 533.48
AIC=-1052.95   AICc=-1052.65   BIC=-1025.43

Training set error measures:
                       ME       RMSE        MAE  MPE MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set 0.0002524145 0.05785966 0.03492112 -Inf  Inf 0.3350916 0.0122546

How do I extract the seasonality directly from the model instead of using stl or decompose? Is it even possible?
dput(for_seasonality)

structure(list(ds = c("2017-02-12", "2017-02-19", "2017-02-26", 
"2017-03-05", "2017-03-12", "2017-03-19", "2017-03-26", "2017-04-02", 
"2017-04-09", "2017-04-16", "2017-04-23", "2017-04-30", "2017-05-07", 
"2017-05-14", "2017-05-21", "2017-05-28", "2017-06-04", "2017-06-11", 
"2017-06-18", "2017-06-25", "2017-07-02", "2017-07-09", "2017-07-16", 
"2017-07-23", "2017-07-30", "2017-08-06", "2017-08-13", "2017-08-20", 
"2017-08-27", "2017-09-03", "2017-09-10", "2017-09-17", "2017-09-24", 
"2017-10-01", "2017-10-08", "2017-10-15", "2017-10-22", "2017-10-29", 
"2017-11-05", "2017-11-12", "2017-11-19", "2017-11-26", "2017-12-03", 
"2017-12-10", "2017-12-17", "2017-12-24", "2017-12-31", "2018-01-07", 
"2018-01-14", "2018-01-21", "2018-01-28", "2018-02-04", "2018-02-11", 
"2018-02-18", "2018-02-25", "2018-03-04", "2018-03-11", "2018-03-18", 
"2018-03-25", "2018-04-01", "2018-04-08", "2018-04-15", "2018-04-22", 
"2018-04-29", "2018-05-06", "2018-05-13", "2018-05-20", "2018-05-27", 
"2018-06-03", "2018-06-10", "2018-06-17", "2018-06-24", "2018-07-01", 
"2018-07-08", "2018-07-15", "2018-07-22", "2018-07-29", "2018-08-05", 
"2018-08-12", "2018-08-19", "2018-08-26", "2018-09-02", "2018-09-09", 
"2018-09-16", "2018-09-23", "2018-09-30", "2018-10-07", "2018-10-14", 
"2018-10-21", "2018-10-28", "2018-11-04", "2018-11-11", "2018-11-18", 
"2018-11-25", "2018-12-02", "2018-12-09", "2018-12-16", "2018-12-23", 
"2018-12-30", "2019-01-06", "2019-01-13", "2019-01-20", "2019-01-27", 
"2019-02-03", "2019-02-10", "2019-02-17", "2019-02-24", "2019-03-03", 
"2019-03-10", "2019-03-17", "2019-03-24", "2019-03-31", "2019-04-07", 
"2019-04-14", "2019-04-21", "2019-04-28", "2019-05-05", "2019-05-12", 
"2019-05-19", "2019-05-26", "2019-06-02", "2019-06-09", "2019-06-16", 
"2019-06-23", "2019-06-30", "2019-07-07", "2019-07-14", "2019-07-21", 
"2019-07-28", "2019-08-04", "2019-08-11", "2019-08-18", "2019-08-25", 
"2019-09-01", "2019-09-08", "2019-09-15", "2019-09-22", "2019-09-29", 
"2019-10-06", "2019-10-13", "2019-10-20", "2019-10-27", "2019-11-03", 
"2019-11-10", "2019-11-17", "2019-11-24", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-08", 
"2019-12-15", "2019-12-22", "2019-12-29", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-12", 
"2020-01-19", "2020-01-26", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-09", "2020-02-16", 
"2020-02-23", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-22", 
"2020-03-29", "2020-04-05", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-19", "2020-04-26", 
"2020-05-03", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-17", "2020-05-24", "2020-05-31", 
"2020-06-07", "2020-06-14", "2020-06-21", "2020-06-28", "2020-07-05", 
"2020-07-12", "2020-07-19", "2020-07-26", "2020-08-02", "2020-08-09", 
"2020-08-16", "2020-08-23", "2020-08-30", "2020-09-06", "2020-09-13", 
"2020-09-20", "2020-09-27", "2020-10-04", "2020-10-11", "2020-10-18", 
"2020-10-25", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-08", "2020-11-15", "2020-11-22", 
"2020-11-29", "2020-12-06", "2020-12-13", "2020-12-20", "2020-12-27", 
"2021-01-03", "2021-01-10", "2021-01-17", "2021-01-24", "2021-01-31", 
"2021-02-07", "2021-02-14", "2021-02-21", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-07", 
"2021-03-14", "2021-03-21", "2021-03-28", "2021-04-04", "2021-04-11", 
"2021-04-18", "2021-04-25", "2021-05-02", "2021-05-09", "2021-05-16", 
"2021-05-23", "2021-05-30", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-13", "2021-06-20", 
"2021-06-27", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-11", "2021-07-18", "2021-07-25", 
"2021-08-01", "2021-08-08", "2021-08-15", "2021-08-22", "2021-08-29", 
"2021-09-05", "2021-09-12", "2021-09-19", "2021-09-26", "2021-10-03", 
"2021-10-10", "2021-10-17", "2021-10-24", "2021-10-31", "2021-11-07", 
"2021-11-14", "2021-11-21", "2021-11-28", "2021-12-05", "2021-12-12", 
"2021-12-19", "2021-12-26", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-09", "2022-01-16", 
"2022-01-23", "2022-01-30", "2022-02-06", "2022-02-13", "2022-02-20", 
"2022-02-27", "2022-03-06", "2022-03-13", "2022-03-20", "2022-03-27", 
"2022-04-03", "2022-04-10", "2022-04-17", "2022-04-24", "2022-05-01", 
"2022-05-08", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-22", "2022-05-29", "2022-06-05", 
"2022-06-12", "2022-06-19", "2022-06-26", "2022-07-03", "2022-07-10", 
"2022-07-17", "2022-07-24", "2022-07-31", "2022-08-07", "2022-08-14", 
"2022-08-21", "2022-08-28", "2022-09-04", "2022-09-11", "2022-09-18", 
"2022-09-25", "2022-10-02", "2022-10-09", "2022-10-16", "2022-10-23", 
"2022-10-30", "2022-11-06", "2022-11-13", "2022-11-20", "2022-11-27", 
"2022-12-04", "2022-12-11", "2022-12-18", "2022-12-25", "2023-01-01", 
"2023-01-08", "2023-01-15", "2023-01-22", "2023-01-29", "2023-02-05", 
"2023-02-12", "2023-02-19", "2023-02-26", "2023-03-05", "2023-03-12", 
"2023-03-19", "2023-03-26", "2023-04-02", "2023-04-09", "2023-04-16", 
"2023-04-23", "2023-04-30", "2023-05-07", "2023-05-14", "2023-05-21", 
"2023-05-28", "2023-06-04", "2023-06-11", "2023-06-18", "2023-06-25", 
"2023-07-02", "2023-07-09", "2023-07-16", "2023-07-23", "2023-07-30", 
"2023-08-06", "2023-08-13", "2023-08-20", "2023-08-27", "2023-09-03", 
"2023-09-10", "2023-09-17", "2023-09-24", "2023-10-01", "2023-10-08", 
"2023-10-15", "2023-10-22", "2023-10-29", "2023-11-05", "2023-11-12", 
"2023-11-19", "2023-11-26", "2023-12-03", "2023-12-10", "2023-12-17", 
"2023-12-24", "2023-12-31", "2024-01-07", "2024-01-14", "2024-01-21", 
"2024-01-28", "2024-02-04", "2024-02-11", "2024-02-18", "2024-02-25", 
"2024-03-03", "2024-03-10", "2024-03-17", "2024-03-24", "2024-03-31", 
"2024-04-07", "2024-04-14", "2024-04-21", "2024-04-28", "2024-05-05"
), y = c(0.202898550724638, 0.306010928961749, 0.369294605809129, 
0.349726775956284, 0.318367346938775, 0.202702702702703, 0.0265486725663717, 
0.0116279069767442, 0.0422535211267606, 0.024390243902439, 0.0298507462686567, 
0.0625, 0.0441176470588235, 0.258823529411765, 0.428571428571429, 
0.428571428571429, 0.363636363636364, 0.296296296296296, 0.306451612903226, 
0.337078651685393, 0.357894736842105, 0.315068493150685, 0.0512820512820513, 
0.35, 0.352941176470588, 0.375, 0.322314049586777, 0.307692307692308, 
0.36697247706422, 0.300884955752212, 0.417322834645669, 0.423076923076923, 
0.292134831460674, 0.3125, 0.288288288288288, 0.311475409836066, 
0.311258278145695, 0.27027027027027, 0.410852713178295, 0, 0.274725274725275, 
0.344262295081967, 0.388349514563107, 0.180851063829787, 0.297619047619048, 
0.247311827956989, 0.303030303030303, 0.303030303030303, 0.28, 
0.264864864864865, 0.295833333333333, 0.293193717277487, 0.277777777777778, 
0.286713286713287, 0.358024691358025, 0.265243902439024, 0.405835543766578, 
0.346153846153846, 0.162337662337662, 0.179012345679012, 0.0363636363636364, 
0.0303030303030303, 0.276845637583893, 0.0238095238095238, 0.0207253886010363, 
0.0861344537815126, 0.259920634920635, 0.259574468085106, 0.268738574040219, 
0.189097103918228, 0.249283667621777, 0.0788253477588872, 0.0424710424710425, 
0.0238095238095238, 0.0400641025641026, 0.201511335012594, 0.23789764868603, 
0.251644736842105, 0.193166885676741, 0.174029451137885, 0.156914893617021, 
0.146551724137931, 0.181462140992167, 0.182926829268293, 0.159349593495935, 
0.168587896253602, 0.156204379562044, 0.128398791540786, 0.149532710280374, 
0.171480144404332, 0.184410646387833, 0.131826741996234, 0.153664302600473, 
0.184331797235023, 0.178191489361702, 0.14375, 0.133522727272727, 
0.111486486486486, 0.12216404886562, 0.130057803468208, 0.146666666666667, 
0.110246433203632, 0.141891891891892, 0.120617110799439, 0.211404728789986, 
0.143617021276596, 0.110144927536232, 0.118686868686869, 0.131897711978466, 
0.104143337066069, 0.176788124156545, 0.142276422764228, 0.166666666666667, 
0.16914749661705, 0.163663663663664, 0.162671232876712, 0.128724672228844, 
0.167064439140811, 0.272511848341232, 0.145539906103286, 0.14311377245509, 
0.150844496214327, 0.177789642285104, 0.125, 0.156917363045497, 
0.150943396226415, 0.174657534246575, 0.136182336182336, 0.119266055045872, 
0.104567969179967, 0.140829694323144, 0.160500260552371, 0.177392040643522, 
0.156756756756757, 0.152115211521152, 0.164459632635626, 0.171113934773401, 
0.163983050847458, 0.139417693169093, 0.136820083682008, 0.138376383763838, 
0.169898430286242, 0.171023151605676, 0.123293172690763, 0.128703254006799, 
0.0419927941359175, 0.0140252454417952, 0.0120805369127517, 0.0141043723554302, 
0.0829367777022434, 0.127423822714681, 0.139739823751574, 0.155355041192625, 
0.356070941336971, 0.372844827586207, 0.363636363636364, 0.364014801110083, 
0.370642912470953, 0.369206598586017, 0.381382738364211, 0.411327762302693, 
0.413577274915744, 0.439872153415901, 0.41396789636722, 0.411489151873767, 
0.418884257774928, 0.425267215700018, 0.411823314513451, 0.396557971014493, 
0.435027339980701, 0.417841246290801, 0.456265866605123, 0.423100060156407, 
0.39560639070443, 0.404095035734982, 0.425176946410516, 0.405739817838117, 
0.42874169930189, 0.403052666890305, 0.405996026729276, 0.426771653543307, 
0.420687065890745, 0.433764287052651, 0.375382848392037, 0.415816857440166, 
0.428750260796996, 0.479342418343067, 0.453336020963515, 0.4466, 
0.426112185686654, 0.429136081309994, 0.431360332294912, 0.450557761391567, 
0.382935352358765, 0.389040416563352, 0.443654822335025, 0.444214341185607, 
0.211779531737083, 0.440242494226328, 0.456976744186047, 0.434681783045607, 
0.399182561307902, 0.447032546266752, 0.407063957452611, 0.411091184991033, 
0.410076335877863, 0.433456825306355, 0.401960784313726, 0.409716464931189, 
0.430936368339369, 0.454604620891637, 0.426473288048467, 0.433277498604132, 
0.397947383636889, 0.402411021814007, 0.400862688713156, 0.534119016441147, 
0.567341736297975, 0.543926019335855, 0.549124743731273, 0.537297462549679, 
0.551872314303254, 0.558368708308066, 0.5581499107674, 0.552411204158244, 
0.559005275056518, 0.54605079542283, 0.539087211929507, 0.532849891225526, 
0.538585444428174, 0.556921856406188, 0.550718741524274, 0.537498537498537, 
0.515552614162806, 0.496884041842867, 0.493076390491576, 0.510889856876167, 
0.527698525915359, 0.532745255279337, 0.537957161591141, 0.551650485436893, 
0.537024100593783, 0.548935375420247, 0.565225781551524, 0.574803149606299, 
0.563266800952207, 0.550311497073815, 0.55310621242485, 0.513274336283186, 
0.442897817146473, 0.487274655355249, 0.52077807250221, 0.526984834968778, 
0.478135511773186, 0.461439034898751, 0.467752358795399, 0.488882429879378, 
0.547792706333973, 0.546064814814815, 0.540696306751353, 0.492102985720467, 
0.519038583175206, 0.544230294044972, 0.528761061946903, 0.524969875485339, 
0.513771852597158, 0.517705554208101, 0.511409555502734, 0.536136816211784, 
0.554033835884452, 0.542654867256637, 0.555215099889692, 0.537723273793655, 
0.530873991802195, 0.537483266398929, 0.556653195629397, 0.532146389713155, 
0.55104764446817, 0.5648804833202, 0.538283627510651, 0.530659467797918, 
0.535490220199286, 0.541566883339035, 0.536886993603412, 0.548596341982135, 
0.551193225558122, 0.569143398012305, 0.566444884013667, 0.576183431952663, 
0.582755298651252, 0.591130505378527, 0.590882524839275, 0.582544047255321, 
0.573210698805371, 0.587782952453157, 0.575615972812235, 0.553296819043607, 
0.552618840158776, 0.541631544441322, 0.542762193333985, 0.555849889624724, 
0.259827534939043, 0.546125, 0.549267003124249, 0.522683397683398, 
0.533162939297125, 0.555646630236794, 0.559461805555556, 0.556037666174298, 
0.566134969325153, 0.548941798941799, 0.535668661332616, 0.562672961093928, 
0.546070583954885, 0.532927679533498, 0.529315293152932, 0.529202025244242, 
0.530863198770326, 0.53597150771666, 0.533686475749048, 0.548960636886333, 
0.561969015492254, 0.54733566705562, 0.543695429874931, 0.541476903057905, 
0.551163352387086, 0.566015393724097, 0.551094567047771, 0.540931489429344, 
0.534078031406832, 0.543460056941886, 0.547606072401713, 0.559090159881325, 
0.567992676431425, 0.572674186065115, 0.572841236471229, 0.561493928268851, 
0.562971791815654, 0.569454691796901, 0.571167141114274, 0.515399719495091, 
0.545426025850169, 0.556342842936168, 0.568220367731868, 0.56072539545966, 
0.565971545507698, 0.568579183235498, 0.587616902177623, 0.591906451189068, 
0.585231447465099, 0.560879573540102, 0.570411342106936, 0.568202538747458, 
0.270853193517636, 0.551398059835331, 0.533085777942815, 0.51456047677096, 
0.538433193308276, 0.550130039011704, 0.569489624228828, 0.549147336087279, 
0.553869876641464, 0.560376541874053, 0.546383647798742, 0.561126336718792, 
0.559784185183037, 0.55080791989076, 0.527637645782479, 0.543261278731535, 
0.544410633289315, 0.544132509825941, 0.538864827900615, 0.544048709520987, 
0.550511691727174, 0.56661750245821, 0.553677932405567, 0.555667297681022, 
0.558367683429514), week_num = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 
74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 
90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 
105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 
118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 
131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 
144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 
157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 
170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 
183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 
196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 
209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 
222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 
235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 
248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 
261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 
274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 
287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 
300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 
313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 
326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 
339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 
352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 
365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377
)), row.names = c(NA, -378L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55bc40c22d00>)



I am not sure if I have understood your question clearly, but you can remove seasonality using the diff function. If you have weekly data, this simple code may remove the seasonality.
ts_data <- diff(ts_data, lag = 7)

I'm more looking to see only the seasonality. I am thinking I can use sar1 and sar2 and plot it but not sure if that would work. From what I've seen it's not possible
